# Evaluate the integral $(3x-2)/(x+1)$

Tags: calculus, integration

The answer I have which I'm sure is wrong is $(3x-2)\ln(\left \vert x+1 \right \vert + \text{constant}$

I let $x + 1$ be $u$ and $du$ would be $1$. But I didn't know how to get $1$ on top so I just pulled the numerator $(3x-2)$ to the outside and left a $1$ on top.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are wrong. We have $$\dfrac{3x-2}{x+1} = \dfrac{3(x+1)-5}{x+1} = 3 - \dfrac5{x+1}$$
Now integrating this gives us
$$3x-5\ln(\left\vert x+1 \right \vert) + \text{constant}$$

Comment: Did you do 3(x+1) - 5 in the numerator so you could cancel out the (x+1) when you separate them. Like 3(x+1)/(x+1) - 5/(x+1) ?

Comment: @user142342 Yes. This technique goes by the name [partial fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).